# Can't make an animation work WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I can't make this animation work:

```
        <Ellipse Opacity="0.7" Width="150" Height="50" StrokeThickness="5">
        <Ellipse.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True">
                                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="100" Duration="0:0:2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.Y" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
        </Ellipse.Triggers>
    </Ellipse>
```

Basically it's an `Ellipse` that translates from a starting point at Y to an ending point of Y. But basically, it doesn't move, and launches a mistake... Any ideas?

Comment: I thought so, as I found this:
<Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Height="20.2" Canvas.Left="-10.033" Canvas.Top="-10.167" Width="20.2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
           <Ellipse.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
             <ScaleTransform/>
             <SkewTransform/>
             <RotateTransform/>
             <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
           </Ellipse.LayoutTransform>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep it simple you can put ellipsis in a canvas :

```
 <Canvas>
            <Ellipse Width="30" Height="30" Fill="Purple" Canvas.Top="0" >
                <Ellipse.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded" >
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:5"  AutoReverse="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" To="100" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Ellipse.Triggers>
            </Ellipse>
        </Canvas>
```

Comment: It works! What about if I want to route if to a specific event that I launch on my code, not the `Ellipse.Loaded`?

Comment: FrameworkElement.Loaded can work too, it's just my way of coding. Answer updated

Comment: But keep in mind that animating `Canvas.Top` involves layout (at least the arrange pass), whereas animating `RenderTransform` doesn't. You may run into performance issues when you do this with many objects.

Comment: @Sonhja Sorry, my remark about performance was meant for you.

Answer (score 2):

Animating the `LayoutTransform` will not move the object. What you are looking for is an animation of the [RenderTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx) property:

You have to put a [TranslateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.translatetransform.aspx) into `Ellipse.RenderTransform` and change `Storyboard.TargetProperty`:

```
<Ellipse Opacity="0.7" Width="150" Height="50" StrokeThickness="5" Stroke="Black">
    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform />
    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    <Ellipse.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True">
                        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="100" Duration="0:0:2"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Y" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Ellipse.Triggers>
</Ellipse>
```